# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea

i'm doing some practice in Arrays using Intellij idea first time, But it's giving me this errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at ArrayDemo.main(ArrayDemo.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Why i'm getting this, will anyone please tell me the reason?

here is my program:

```
public class ArrayDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] copyFrom={'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
        char[] copyTo=new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample tries to copy 7 of `copyFrom` items starting by the index 2. However there is no item indexed 2+7 = 9 in the `copyFrom` array that's why you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Look at the parameters.

> Parameters:
>   `src` the source array.
>   `srcPos` starting position in the source array.
>   `dest` the destination array.
>   `destPos` starting position in the destination data.
>   **`length` the number of array elements to be copied.**

Try this code:

```
public class ArrayDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] copyFrom={'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
        char[] copyTo=new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0,5);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Comment: How come above code works? destination length is 5 and starting at 0 but source lenght is 7 ?

Comment: okay one thing can you tell me, when i use `(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 2, 5)` using `2` instead `0` it throws again that `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception... why?

Comment: @user3573302 2+5 = 7, but the last index of 7 sized array is 6.

Comment: but this outputs only cefgg not whole array as source array starts from 2

Comment: a -> 0 index, b-> 1 index then c-> 2 index where c starts from 2 then the method copies 5 following items in the source array whose are "cefgg" as expected. @KaribasappaGC

Answer (score 4):

If you start copying from position 2 then you cannot copy 7 items, you can only copy 5

Comment: ya it's working thanks.... but can you tell me inside `(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 4)` what's the use of `0` in this??

Comment: o is the starting position in destination array

Answer (score 2):

As said in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

> ```
> public static void arraycopy(Object src,
>              int srcPos,
>              Object dest,
>              int destPos,
>              int length)
> ```
>
> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the
>   specified position, to the specified position of the destination
>   array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source
>   array referenced by `src` to the destination array referenced by dest.
>   The number of components copied is equal to the length argument. The
>   components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos+length-1` in the
>   source array are copied into positions destPos through
>   `destPos+length-1`, respectively, of the destination array.

Thus this code:

```
char[] copyFrom = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
char[] copyTo = new char[7];
System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 7);
```

Can not be used to copy 7 elements. If you need to copy 7 elements, you can use the following example:

```
public class ArrayDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] copyFrom = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
        char[] copyTo = new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abcefgg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length);
```

where

- `src` -- This is the source array.
- `srcPos` -- This is the starting position in the source array.
- `dest` -- This is the destination array.
- `destPos` -- This is the starting position in the destination data.
- `length` -- This is the number of array elements to be copied.

So either change destination length to 5 like below

```
char[] copyFrom={'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
        char[] copyTo=new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 2, copyTo, 0, 5);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
```

or start source from 0 instead of 2 like below

```
char[] copyFrom={'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'};
        char[] copyTo=new char[7];

        System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, 5);
        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
```